# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError (No such coumn) in flask framework

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to add images on my flaskblog posts, however, I am facing with the following error:

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: post.post_image
[SQL: SELECT post.id AS post_id, post.title AS post_title, post.date_posted AS post_date_posted, post.content AS post_content, post.user_id AS post_user_id, post.post_image AS post_post_image
FROM post]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

These are my imports in routes.py file

```
import os
import secrets
from PIL import Image
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, request, abort
from flaskblog import app, db, bcrypt
from flaskblog.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm, UpdateAccountForm, PostForm
from flaskblog.models import User, Post
from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required
```

This is my new_post function and new post route in routes.py file

```
@app.route("/post/new", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_post():
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.post_picture.data:
            image_post = save_picture(form.picture.data)
            form.post_picture = image_post
        post = Post(title=form.title.data, content=form.content.data, author=current_user, post_image= form.post_picture.data)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your post has been created!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    image_file = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/')
    return render_template('create_post.html', title='New Post', image_file=image_file,
                           form=form, legend='New Post')
```

This is my imports in form.py file

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed
from flask_login import current_user
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo, ValidationError
from flaskblog.models import User
```

this is my PostForm class in forms.py file

```
from datetime import datetime
from flaskblog import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    post_image = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

regarding these codes, what do you think I should do in order to fix this error? Thank you.

edit1:

This is my **init**.py file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '5791628bb0b13ce0c676dfde280ba245'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'

from flaskblog import routes
```

edit2: I am having the following error after dropping tables from the db.

[image]

This is the blog post view

[image]

Comment: Can you share the __init__.py code? If is not called that then the file where you connect SQLalchemy to the app? Full code please

Comment: You're right, thank you. I just edited my question, please check.

Comment: Ok i think the issue is in the Post model. I post the answer now hold on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you newly added the `post_image` field to the Post model?

If so, you'd need to either

- use a database migration tool like [Alembic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/) to generate and apply the SQL statements to alter the table, or
- add the suitable column into the table by hand (tedious), or
- drop the table and recreate it (**destroying all data; dangerous**)

Comment: Yes I recently added post_image to the model. I can drop the table actually, the data is nothing but dummy data since this is just a test blog

Comment: Hi there again, I just dropped the table and able to login to my blog through localhost. Now I want to add image to my post however I receive this  errors 
qlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: post.post_image
[SQL: INSERT INTO post (title, date_posted, content, user_id, post_image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('s', '2020-08-10 07:42:58.864233', 's', 1, None)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)

Comment: Well, you've declared the image as a non-nullable field, which means it must have a value. You're not setting a value.

Comment: I see, when I make it nullable, the problem seems to be solved. Thank you!